# How to match a part of a string with array values using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a javascript array:

```
var exclude = ["Santorum","Obama","Romney","Gingrich"];
```

I have html links:

```
<a href="" class="title">Santorum is seeking campaign funding</a>
<a href="" class="title">Clinton is stepping down as Secretary</a>
<a href="" class="title">Obama is seeking reelection</a>
```

I want to check whether any of the a-links have any one of the exclude-values in them, and if they do, then remove them. So the result would be:

```
<a href="" class="title">Clinton is stepping down as Secretary</a>
```

The other two would be removed as they possess words from the array. I've tried using jQuery.inArray but I can't seem to figure it out. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
var exclude = ["Santorum","Obama","Romney","Gingrich"];

$('a.title').filter($.map(exclude, function (val) {
    return ':contains("' + val + '")';
}).join()).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SxP2a/

Comment: thx, it works. what if I want to remove a div that encompasses the a-link?

Comment: @Tomi then just add `.closest('div')` before `remove()`

Answer (score 2):

Try looping though the excluded words, and remove links that have them.

For example (using the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)):

```
$.each(exclude, function(i, v){
    $('a.title:contains("'+v+'")').remove();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/H6FPb/

EDIT: You said the `<a>` is wrapped in a `<div>`, then you can do:

```
$.each(exclude, function(i, v){
    $('a.title:contains("'+v+'")').parent('div').remove();
});
```

Comment: thx, it works. what if I want to remove a div that encompasses the a-link?

Comment: @TomiSeus: Then you'd do `.parent('div').remove()`